# elm function in nnfor package does not recognize input for xreg

Tags: r

I'm trying to include an exogenous regressor in my time series analysis

```
elm_nn<-elm(ts(df), 
            m=1, 
            hd=NULL,
            type="step",
            reps = 20,
            comb = "median", 
            difforder = c(0:12), 
            outplot =TRUE, 
            sel.lag=FALSE,
            direct = FALSE,
            allow.det.season = TRUE,
            det.type = "auto",
            xreg =reg)
```

Using

```
df<-c(0,0,173,0,0,80,0)
reg<-c(182,135,30,203,150,83,163)
```

Information in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnfor/nnfor.pdf) alludes to xreg being a column, presumably from a table. I had a vector that I had used as an xreg when using ARIMA where it performed without issue. Using the same vector in elm however generates the error `Error in xreg[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`. I can't find information regarding exogenous regressors for extreme learning machines that deals specifically with time series. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when I converted the list to a table, R added an additional column with alphanumeric values in the new column that looked like`A1,B1,...,Z1,A2,...` called Var1. Trying to remove this column converted it into a single row and generated the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In reg$Var1 <- NULL : Coercing LHS to a list
```

By converting the vector to a data frame instead, I was able to use it without issue.